In below `gt` nest table ,how can i change the text color and size
In below gt nest table ,how can i change the text color and size ?
I added color and size to gt , it's can't work.  Anyone can help  ? Thanks!
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

nested_data <- diamonds %>% head(10)%>% group_by(color) %>% 
  summarise(x=list(x),y=list(y))

nested_data %>% gt() # result as attached image



In the example below, I create a table of average values for x and y by color. Then, I set text red color for all x values with an average greater than 4.4 and blue for the average values of x and y where color == "J".
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

color_num <- function(x, k) {
   filt <- (x > k)
   x <- as.character(x)
   x[filt] <- paste0("<span style='color:red;'>",x[filt],"</span>")
   x <- paste0(x, collapse=", ")
   return(x)
}

nested_data <- diamonds %>% 
               head(10)%>% 
               group_by(color) %>% 
               summarise(x=list(color_num(x, 4)), 
                         y=list(y))

nested_data %>% 
   gt() %>%
   fmt_markdown(columns = x)



@Macro Thanks for the sample. Is the way for this apply to nested data ? Thanks!

I edited my post ,maybe it's more clear. Coluld help on it ? Thanks!
